# gzip *.txt vs gzip test.txt & gzip test2.txt &

Tags: performance, gzip, parallelism

I am looking to speedup gzip process. (server is AIX 7.1)

More specificly, the current implementation is with `gzip *.txt` and it takes up to 1h to complete.
(file extractions are quite big and we got a total of 10 files)

Question: Will it be more efficient to run

```
pids=""
gzip file1.txt &
pids+=" $!"
gzip file2.txt &
pids+=" $!"
wait $pids
```

than

```
gzip *.txt
```

Is the `gzip *txt` behavior is the same in terms of parallelism, cpu consumption etc as the gzip in the background (&) or the other option will be more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. You can use `pigz`, a parallel implementation of `gzip` which should be in your distributions repositories. If it isn't, you can get it from [here](http://www.zlib.net/pigz/).

Once you've installed `pigz`, use it as you would `gzip`:

```
pigz *txt
```

I tested this on 5 30M files created using `for i in {1..5}; do head -c 50M /dev/urandom > file"$i".txt; done`:

```
## Non-parallel gzip
$ time gzip *txt
real    0m8.853s
user    0m8.607s
sys     0m0.243s

## Shell parallelization (same idea as yours, just simplified)
$ time ( for i in *txt; do gzip $i & done; wait)

real    0m2.214s
user    0m10.230s
sys     0m0.250s

## pigz
$ time pigz *txt

real    0m1.689s
user    0m11.580s
sys     0m0.317s
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.Unfortunatly i do AppSupport and is troublesome in terms of internal process to install a new package. your times provided much food for thought and answerd my questions :) i will use your feedback as basis for further tests. Ofc i have to consider and @Bob Eager s feedback for the disk contention

Comment: @GiannakopoulosJ yes, that will almost certainly be the main bottleneck. As a general rule, parallelization can only help until you hit your maximum read speed from the disk.

Comment: @GiannakopoulosJ you should also look into GNU parallel if you're doing this sort of thing. It is extremely useful and its developer is very active on this site so you can ask here if you have trouble with it. Kalh tyxh!

Answer (score 1):

The only real way is to time it. I would expect `gzip *.txt` to do them one at a time, as they are separate files.

Running them in parallel (using `gzip file1.txt` etc.) *might* be faster, but it will depend on how much memory you have, how many CPU cores, etc. The most important factor is that you'll get contention for the disk while you're doing it, and that could slow things a lot (unless it's an SSD, and even then to some extent). They'll both use a similar amount of CPU time in total.

I generally use `gzip *.txt` or similar.

Comment: Based on your input the gzip *txt will perform the actions serial one text after another while the gzip file1.txt & ... will go in parallel. CPU core# and memory is not an issue. I will have to check it further with tests.

Comment: I'd think disk contention would be the real issue.